# Updating mysql localhost database from remote server

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables with same rows and columns one is on my localhost and second is on a remote server.

What I want is that if some one will add any data to my online remote server it should make an entry automatically to my localhost database.

Is there any way to use a trigger or anything else I can do..

Comment: Are you able to use replication? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html

Comment: Have a look at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/federated-description.html

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [Replication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication.html). Note that you *could* do it with a FEDERATED table, but that is extremely slow at best, and should *not* be used because of both reliability & performance reasons.

Comment: thanks wrikken so is there any other way apart from replication...?

Comment: Not a reliable one that I know of. You could fiddle about with some custom build udf's, but really, replication is what you want (and can be easily implemented on any VPS or server, but on shared hosting it's probably a no go).

Answer (score 0):

You may want to set up a cron job on your server that executes a php script that checks for new rows in your remote database every few minutes and adds them to the local database.